# is it possible to transfer row from qtablewidget to another qtablewidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a row with text data in some cells and other cells have widgets in it, Can I transfer these cells in the row, so I mean the whole row to another qtablewidget without having to break the row into small data then rebuild it again into the other qtablewidget?
Note: please don't ask me for minimal pro-- because I'm only asking before doing it so I be aware what's waiting for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function like that for QTableWidget (the only similar function only exists for QStandardItemModel: [`takeRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#takeRow)).

In order to remove items you need to use [`insertRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#insertRow) on the target table, [`takeItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#takeItem) for each column in the source row, and [`setItem()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#setItem) on the target, and finally [`removeRow()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#removeRow).

```
    def moveRow(self, row):
        targetRow = self.target.rowCount()
        self.target.insertRow(targetRow)
        for column in range(self.source.columnCount()):
            item = self.source.takeItem(row, column)
            if item:
                self.target.setItem(targetRow, column, item)
        self.source.removeRow(row)
```

Unfortunately, this won't let you do anything for cell widgets. When a widget is set on a cell in an item view, the view will take complete and *definitive* ownership on the widget: even if you try to use `removeWidget` or `setCellWidget` with another widget, the previous one will be deleted *internally* by Qt (see the sources for [`QAbstractItemView.setIndexWidget()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp#L3168), which is called for both `removeWidget` *and* `setCellWidget`).

The only solution would be to check if the cell has a widget, create a new instance of the same class and copy its properties.

A possible workaround is to add cell widgets using a *container* widget with a layout, add the actual widgets to that layout, and then create a new container and set the layout for it:

```
    # add a container for the actual widget
    container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    contLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
    # layout usually add some margins to their widgets, let's remove them
    contLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    testButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('test')
    contLayout.addWidget(testButton)
    self.source.setCellWidget(0, 0, container)

def moveRow(self, row):
    # ...
        widget = self.source.cellWidget(row, column)
        if widget and widget.layout() is not None:
            newContainer = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            newContainer.setLayout(widget.layout())
            self.target.setCellWidget(targetRow, column, newContainer)
    self.source.removeRow(row)
```

Comment: Can i copy the widget inside the cell (qvboxlayout and inside it some widgets) at once without going through building it from scratch ? @musicamante

Comment: Well, yes, it would not be very *elegant*, but it could be a possible workaround. I've updated the answer accordingly.